# Plot a state graph based on events indicating state changes

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, kibana, grafana, dashboard

I have an Elasticsearch instance in which I store events corresponding to the state changes of some resource. For instance, I have a resource that can be in 3 states : OK, WARNING, or CRITICAL.
When the state of that resource change from let's say OK to WARNING, an event is created in elasticsearch with the time of the event and the new state (WARNING).

I would like to create a line chart with the time on x and the state on y (with OK=0, WARNING=1, CRITICAL=2). The chart should be updated every 5s with the new point corresponding to the state of the last event.

The events can come in every minute, hours or days, so they don't have a fixed interval, which seems to be problematic with Kibana (I looked at timelion).

Any idea on how to do that ? Maybe with grafana or another dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same need and ended up creating a custom exporter with the `status -> number` mapping logic - Prometheus then collects data from this exporter and we can use Grafana to visualise it.

Not ideal but works. I would be interested to hear about other ways of solving it.